# insert padding to bootstrap column grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have designed web form in bootstrap v3.

I want to add spaces between text-box and labels in this form with maintaining its responsiveness.

Its 4 Column grid (Medium & Large Devices) & 2 Column grid ( Small Devices)

jsfiddle : **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LXary/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you're wanting? http://jsfiddle.net/ZaTc6/

Comment: Yes. But you compromised on responsiveness....when i drag fiddler screen to max it does not switch to 4 column :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.form-group` elements are collapsing upon themselves because their children elements are being floated. To solve this, either add a clearfix or add `overflow:hidden`. Unfortunately, in doing so, the form doesn't maintain responsiveness, therefore you can use the following CSS to fix it. In short, this floats every other `.form-group` element when the screen size is greater than `992px`.

[**Updated Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hKgdf/)

```
@media(min-width:992px) {
    .form-group {
        width:50%;
    }
    .form-group:nth-child(2n) {
        float:right;
    }
    .form-group:nth-child(2n + 1) {
        float:left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why in my example textbox gets shrink when screen size is max ? http://jsfiddle.net/LXary/2/

Comment: @SagarDumbre I forgot to mention that I tweaked the HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

want to be fully responsive form?

something like this adds the column col-sm

```
  <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 control-label" for="Title">Title</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LXary/1/